# How Many Cases We Have for Multiset Combinatorics Confined in Total Number

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to count the following casese:

We have a set. We have $n$ different elements. But we can only contain total 50 elements in a set. Moreover, this set is a multi-set, i.e., we can select a element duplicatively in a constraint of 50 total elements.

So how many cases we have in total?

Comment: Let the "$n$ different elements" be labeled $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$.  Let $x_1$ be the number of times $e_1$ is used in our set, $x_2$ the number of times $e_2$ is used, etc...  It sounds like you are asking for the number of integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n=50\\\forall i~~0\leq x_i\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$.  This is a well known problem solvable via [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Simple modifications can be made to the problem if you wanted $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n\leq 50$ instead.

Comment: is that $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$?

Comment: Assuming my interpretation is the correct one, and $n$ is for the $n$ different elements and $k$ is for the $50$ in your problem, yes.

Comment: @then which counting does $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ refer to?

Comment: @delinco $\binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}$, so the answer can be expressed in the form $\binom{n + 50 - 1}{50} = \binom{n + 50 - 1}{n - 1}$ if there are exactly $50$ elements.  If you mean up to $50$ elements, then you want to solve the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n \leq 50$ in the nonnegative integers, which can be converted into the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n + s = 50$ in the nonnegative integers, where $s = 50 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n)$.  Consequently, the inequality has $\binom{n + 50}{n} = \binom{n + 50}{50}$ solutions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig what I only know about counting is "we construct bijection to prove two different counting math-object has a same count". I can't prove how could I make bijective function in this case that show my statement same to the case of choosing $k$ among $n+k-1$. any hint to start make that bijection?

Comment: @delinco  I will respond later.

Comment: Upon rereading this, I realize that the answer above is only valid if each element in the multiset has multiplicity at least $50$.  If at least one of the elements does not have multiplicity at least $50$, we need to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle or generating functions to solve the problem.  Should we make the assumption that each element in the multiset has multiplicity at least $50$?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig you mean.. at most 50? If a element has multiplicity at least 50, there would be only total 50 cases -

Comment: The formula $\binom{n + k - 1}{k}$ counts the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2  + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$ when there are at least $k$ elements available for each of the $n$ types of elements.  Based on your response, you seem to be asking about the number of subsets of a multiset of $50$ elements that has $n$ types of elements.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah it's correct. But every item be assumed to be infite to choose , i.e., they are all more than 50

Comment: This problem starts from my company. Marketing team says they have 50 different products and want to exhaustively list the cases where the total number of the multi-set selection of those 50 prdoucts summed up to 50.

Answer (score 0):

i will use Generating function to solve it

the problem asks for

coefficient of $x^{50}$ in expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....)^{n}$

coefficient of $x^{50}$ in expansion of $\dfrac{1}{({1-x})^n}=(1-x)^{-n}$

we know, coff. of $x^{r}$ in expansion of $(1-x)^{-n}=^{n+r-1}C_{r} \ =\ ^{n+r-1}C_{n-1}$

so,

coefficient of $x^{50}$ in expansion of $(1-x)^{-n}=^{n+49}C_{50}\ =\ ^{n+49}C_{n-1}$